# Is there a way to programmatically join an AWS Chime SDK meeting with a variable number of attendees?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I successfully built a React + Electron application to create and join meetings using AWS Chime SDK. I want to build a tool or small app of some sort that I can use to join a started meeting programmatically with a given number of dummy attendees, for testing purposes (e.g. to create 100 attendees).

Is there a way to easily achieve that? There's no need for audio/video for now.

I tried using the CLI to achieve this, by leveraging the API I built to create the attendee and get their session (incl. join token) using simple curl commands, but I have no idea how to join the meeting.

**Later edit:** The CLI approach doesn't seem to work, so I created a simple React app instead, using the [AWS Chime SDK Component Library React](https://aws.github.io/amazon-chime-sdk-component-library-react). I'm trying to figure out if I need a single `MediaManager` or multiple ones for each attendee.

Comment: I doubt they would allow this; it's a clear vector for spam, and I can't think of a legitimate need. All downside, no upside.